# Debezium Kafka connect. Decimal schema error

Tags: postgresql, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform, debezium

I'm using PostgreSQL.
In my table numeric column defined like this:

```
"net_weight" numeric(19,2)
```

But in Kafka, I'm receiving instead of decimal numbers (E.g. 14.0) I'm getting something like "E4g="

versions:
debezium/connect:0.7
kafka 0.11.0.0
zookeeper 3.4.9

does someone know how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`NUMERIC` column can be encoded as BigDecimal binary value (that you see now), `double` or `string`. Please see `decimal.handling.mode` configuration option.
You either need to decode the value back - https://debezium.io/docs/faq/#how_to_retrieve_decimal_field_from_binary_representation or you can use the other formats. Beware in case of `double` you risk losing precision.

Comment: I've set `decimal.handling.mode` to `string` or `double` for `money` type and it still shows up as decimal in the avro schema. any idea?